# download image file from s3 server in cordova using filetransfer plugin

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-s3, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

i am trying to download images from s3 server using cordova-plugin-file-transfer

my code works with other images from google or diffrent servers.
but when i tried to download from s3 it shows error.

```
downloadimg ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/img/5.jpg";           
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(downloadimg);
var package_root = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + ".appname";
var imgindex = downloadimg.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
var imgname = downloadimg.substr(imgindex);
var fileURL = package_root + imgname;
console.log(uri);
console.log(fileURL);
fileTransfer.download(
uri,
fileURL,
function (entry) {
console.log("success");
},
function (error) {
    console.dir(error);
},
false,
{
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
}
);
```

i tried adding {encodeURI:false}; and 'Content-type':'image/jpg' in option header but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Enable CORS configuration.
2. Remove header auth
3. Check buckets policy (you can test making the object public)

Hope to help you.

Comment: please post your CORS configuration

Comment: <CORSConfiguration>
        <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
       <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
       </CORSRule>
       </CORSConfiguration>

Comment: i have set content-Type : image in metadata and for content-Disposition only "attachement" option available 
if i set content-Disposition to attachement the image url directly get downloads in chrome , does not display image.

Comment: ok, I thought that you need download image, remove attachment ;)

Comment: Please, Make public this image and try again

Comment: Also remove header auth